# python3 sum two different sized lists but without repeat

Tags: python-3.x

```
pay = [1120, 1176, 1232, 1288, 1344, 1400, 1456, 1512, 1568, 1624, 1680, 1736, 1792, 1848, 1904, 1960, 2016, 2072, 2128, 2184, 2240]

rebate = [260.0, 218.0, 176.0, 134.0, 92.0, 50.0, 8.0]
```

I want to total the two lists above.  Since they're different length lists I just want it when the rebate list ends it just continues with the pay list. Total is the same length as pay.

Closest I got was

```
>>>[x+y for x,y in zip(pay,rebate)]
[1380.0, 1394.0, 1408.0, 1422.0, 1436.0, 1450.0, 1464.0]

>>>[x+y for x,y in zip_longest(pay,rebate)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
```

Also tried

```
total = map(lambda x,y: x+y, pay,rebate)
print(list(total))
[1380.0, 1394.0, 1408.0, 1422.0, 1436.0, 1450.0, 1464.0]
```

But it forces equal sized lists.  I just want to leave pay alone once adding rebate is finished.  Similar questions have the same problem; either repeat the smaller list or only return their sum but limited by the shortest list.  I would like to get the full list

I can make a regular for-loop that builds a chart but I'm looking for a way to manipulate two separate lists and sum their contents.  Maybe pass a default size somehow?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You say "Since they're different length lists I just want it ...". What is "it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need the `fillvalue` feature of [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
[a + b for a, b in zip_longest(pay, rebate, fillvalue=0)]
```

Giving

```
[1380.0, 1394.0, 1408.0, 1422.0, 1436.0, 1450.0, 1464.0, 1512,
 1568, 1624, 1680, 1736, 1792, 1848, 1904, 1960, 2016, 2072,
 2128, 2184, 2240]
```

Comment: ahha!  I had typed fillValue=None in a previous attempt and just figured I got it all wrong.  Typo and wrong evaluation combined but right choice.  I'll mark your answer as correct when permitted.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As @Jacques suggested, the answer lays in zip_longest. This is the complete code if you're interested:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

pay = [1120, 1176, 1232, 1288, 1344, 1400, 1456, 1512, 1568, 1624,
       1680, 1736, 1792, 1848, 1904, 1960, 2016, 2072, 2128, 2184, 2240]
rebate = [260.0, 218.0, 176.0, 134.0, 92.0, 50.0, 8.0]

total = [a + b for a, b in zip_longest(pay, rebate, fillvalue=0)]

print(total)
```